# Google Sheet script: PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING option not working with copyTo method

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to copy conditional formatting from a GS range to another range and nothing is copied (no error). This is the snippet:

`spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet_source').getRange(14,7,200,19).copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet_target').getRange(14,7,200,19), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING, false);`

If I use the same code but change the CopyPasteType to a different option, it works (see example below). The problem is that I only want conditional formatting copied so I need the PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING to work. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

`spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet_source').getRange(14,7,200,19).copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet_target').getRange(14,7,200,19), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);`

Per doubleunary's suggestion, I reformatted the script as follows, and it works:

```
function CndFmtFromTmplt_PasteCndFmt() {
  //get spreadsheet
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //get sheets
    const sheetSource = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Template");
    const sheetTarget = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Test Sheet");

  //clear rules
    sheetTarget.clearConditionalFormatRules(); 

  //get copy ranges
    //const rangeSource = sheetSource.getRange(1, 1, sheetSource.getMaxRows(), sheetSource.getMaxColumns());
    const rangeSource = sheetSource.getRange('A1:AF200');
    const rangeTarget = sheetTarget.getRange('A1:AF200');

  // copy values to destination range
  rangeSource.copyTo(rangeTarget, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING,false);
};
```

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show looks fine, so it is unclear where the problem is. To make debugging easier, try structuring your code a bit, like this:

```
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sourceRange = ss.getRange('sheet_source!N7:S200');
  const targetRange = ss.getRange('sheet_target!N7');
  sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING, false);
}
```

Check [My Executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions) for failed executions, and view those logs to learn more about why the function fails. You can run the `test()` function in the script editor when testing.

Comment: thank you for the response. In my original test I used the script generated by the macro recorder. Following your advice, I reformatted the script and now it works. I can't tell why it didn't work before... I am adding the modified script to the original question.